# React-Native- Using DrawerLayoutAndroid to navigate in place of TabBarIos

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I made a react native app in ios before building for android. I created a second component that is supposed to function in stead of tabbarios, named both files the same and just changed the tabbar one to .ios.js and the one with drawerlayoutandroid to .android.js. In both files I'm using my Navigator component, and have
 initialRoute = {{ ident: this.state.selectedTab }} and that is this.state = {selectedTab: "MyFirstScreen"}
My Issue is in the DrawerLayoutAndroid side menu I have three items with TouchableOpacity that have an onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTab: "WhateverTheNewScreenShouldBe"})
When I press those components I had thought that the state would update and show the newly rendered screen but it isn't updated at all. What am I missing?

Comment: Just to check, but does it help to restart the packager?

Comment: i restarted the packager, didn't work

Comment: I might be stating the obvious, but in a similar situation I had accidentally come to the situation where I did an import from 'component.ios' in stead of just from 'component' and having the system figure out what file I needed. Are your imports correct?

Comment: Yeah, the AppNavigator component that I made that uses Navigator doesn't have any code that would be exclusive to ios or android. The component that I'm using as the (unfortunately names BottomBar) has both .ios.js and .android.js. The ios one uses TabBarIos with Icon.TabBarItemIOS with <AppNavigator> being called nested within them. All of those AppNavigator components have an initialRoute={{ident: "SomeScreen"}}. The TabBarItemIOS have a selected={this.state.selectedTab === "someTab"}